# Ionic, Js, React Function Call without callling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

Alright, so I have this function:

```
const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
  path: fileName,
  data: base64Data,
  directory: Directory.Data,
});
```

Now the thing that is puzzling me is the fact that the code inside this function is ran even though I don't have a call to it anywhere in my application.

I get this eslint message:

```
'savedFile' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
'savedFile' is assigned a value but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Can someone please explain to me how is it tit works in this way and why?

Thanks!

What I assume is the correct way to interpret it is that the savedFile const is only a variable that holds the return value of the async call. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This eslint error is telling you that `const savedFiles` is not being used anywhere else besides the code you provided. If savedFiles is being assigned inside your function is it actually being used anywhere else in that function like `return savedfiles`
Yes savedFiles holds the value returned from the async function call `await Filesystem.writeFile()`

```
// savedFiles is declared but not being used or (accessed) for its value
const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({ 
  path: fileName,
  data: base64Data,
  directory: Directory.Data,
});
```